# SqlDependency, Service Broker что на что изменилось, как отследить

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server

Правильно ли я понимаю что Service Broker передает только какая выполнилась команда и не передает где и что изменилось? Мне необходимо выполнять некую функцию только в случае если значение определенного поля изменилось с 0 на 1. Я начал костылять реализовывая подключения к БД внутри метода обработчика события и перед тем как выполнить команду проверял что же у меня там сейчас, но это будет работать в случае если мы знаем какая именно строка(`id`) и какой столбец в БД изменяется. Вопрос, как получить информацию где и что на что изменилось? То есть если в моем запросе несколько столбцов, которые я отслеживаю, было бы не плохо получить во время изменения : имя столбца где прошло изменение, предыдущее значение, на что поменялось и например(`id`) записи. Вот например триггер на столбце в БД :

```
BEGIN
    if (UPDATE(id_shiftStatus))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @statusBefore int = (SELECT TOP 1 id_shiftStatus FROM DELETED)
        DECLARE @statusAfter int = (SELECT TOP 1 id_shiftStatus FROM INSERTED)
        DECLARE @id int = (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM INSERTED)
   END
END
```

Вот так я понимаю что на что изменилось и знаю id записи где это случилось, касательно столбца как бы он зараниее известен. Но как поступить с Service Broker?

Реализация `SubscriptionsWatcher`

```
class SubscriptionsWatcher
{
    private const string connectionString = "";
    private Dashboard dashboard;
    private int variableValue;

    public SubscriptionsWatcher(Dashboard dashboard)
    {
        this.dashboard = dashboard;
    }

    public void StartWatching()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(connectionString);
        SqlDependency.Start(connectionString);
        ExecuteWatchingQuery();
    }

    private void ExecuteWatchingQuery()
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select intTest from dbo.test", connection))
            {
                SqlDependency sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command);                    
                sqlDependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(OnDatabaseChange);

                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDatabaseChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        SqlNotificationInfo info = args.Info;
        if (SqlNotificationInfo.Update.Equals(info))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Its work");
        }

        ExecuteWatchingQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если нужно знать что на что поменялось - используйте Change Tracking: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server

Comment: @PashaPash но это же для SQL, мне в ПО нужно отлавливать что на что поменялось, или я что то недопонимаю?

Comment: в ПО вы можете получить только уведомление. которое придет после того, как что-то поменялось. А узнать, что именно и на что можно только в момент смены, через change tracking. Так что вам стоит включить change tracking и по уведомлению sql dependency лезть в таблицу change tracking и искать изменения.

Comment: Но вообще стоит учитывать, что SqlDependency задуман не как прямое уведомление об изменении, а как уведомление о том, закэшированное значение стало невалидным. А для получения нового валидного закэшированного значения не нужно знать, что именно поменялось. Т.е. отслеживать конкретные изменения только через SqlDependency в принципе не получится.

Comment: @PashaPash Не могу понять, select * from CHANGETABLE(CHANGES [dbo].[test],0) as t, я вижу тут только id записи, но не вижу что на что было поменяно

Comment: `... WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)`

Comment: @PashaPash включено, в свойствах таблицы видно. Но поля где должны быть имена столбцов null.